# SKStoreProductViewController giving Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=5 Error with iOS7

Tags: objective-c, app-store, ios7, skproduct

In my app I have links to other apps on the app store which I open with a SKStoreProductViewController. This worked fine on iOS 6 but I recently installed Xcode 5 and ran this on the iOS7 simulator and now when I try and open the app link in the SKStoreProductViewController I get the following error:

Failed to load product: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=5 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo=0xc188670

*Code = 5 corresponds to the error SKErrorStoreProductNotAvailable: "Indicates that the requested product is not available in the store."

The weird thing is that when I compile this same code from Xcode 5 and run it on a test device using iOS6 the SKStoreProductViewController is working again and opening the app store as it should.

Anyone else had this problem and figured out what is going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug or pending feature for Xcode5. Please have a look at [Xcode5 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html), you will need app store credentials to check.

They have mentioned it like it will not work in the simulator.

Comment: Thanks, didn't see this earlier